Connect to multiple Firestore databases
Currently, I am working on an Angular + Firebase project using the Blaze plan, and I want to know how to connect to multiple Firestore databases within the same Firebase project. However, I haven't found anything in the official Firebase documentation nor in AngularFire.
enter image description here
I have been reading both the Firebase documentation and the AngularFire documentation, but I haven't found any related information.
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore.md

Usign getFirestore(), I can get it
export class FirebaseTestService {
  private firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore); // inject Cloud Firestore
  users$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor() {
    this.firestore = getFirestore('lines');
      // get a reference to the user-profile collection
      const userProfileCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'prueba');

      // get documents (data) from the collection using collectionData
      this.users$ = collectionData(userProfileCollection) as Observable<any[]>;
      this.users$.pipe(
        tap(users => users.forEach(user => console.log(user))) // Imprime cada username recibido
      ).subscribe();
    }
      
  }

